# Laravel 5.3 files table related to multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have one table named "files" which I would like to contain all my users files.
The files can be uploaded from different views and should be related to different tables: questions table, answers table, comments table, messages table etc... but still, all of them will be related also to users table, that way I will know who is the owner of the file.

Example: "user asking a question, and attaching a picture to help other users understand the question more easily."

The question values goes into 'questions_table', the file goes to 'files_table', and the user ID also goes to 'files_table'.

The question is! (sorry for the long introduction):
Should I use a pivot table? or just a double one-to-many relation from 1.'users_table' to 'files_table' & 2.from 'question_table' to 'files_table'?

Comment: I would suggest not having `_table` in the table names. Besides that, are you imagining many files belonging to a single record in the other table? Also, do you want to be able to get to the linked record (question etc) from the file, or do you just wish to get to the file from the linked record?

Comment: This can be solved easily with a 1:n morph on your files table, given that a file can only belong to 1 target (question, answer, etc). For the owner, it's just the id of the creator, which you can add as a column to both the questions and the files tables.

Comment: _table is just to show I'm talking about the table, its not the name of the table. and the thing is, Question belongs to user, File belongs to Question and also belongs to User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the perfect use case for a [Polymorphic Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations).

Here is the structure of the tables:

```
users
 - id
 - name

questions
 - id
 - title

files
 - id
 - user_id
 - filable_id
 - filable_type
```

In the `files` table, you can see a `filable_id` field that is going to reference either a question id, answer id, comment id. And the `filable_type` that is going to tell the record which object is associated with this file.

```
class Question extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the question's files.
     */
    public function files()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\File', 'filable');
    }
}

class File extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning filable models.
     */
    public function filable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

I highly encourage you to learn more about this type of relationship on the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: Thanks mate, thats what I did. just wanna make sure I'm good :)